# Can't receive UDP response after UDP sending on Android device

Tags: android, udp

I have a box, which sends UDP response after receiving UDP packet.
I finally found [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752205/simple-udp-server-for-android-and-get-multi-messages)
how to implement UDP server.
It receives UDP packets okay.

There is a button in my app.
If I tap it I sends UDP packet to the box,
but I don't get the resonse. 
I see that the box receives this packet 
from my Android device and sends the response.
My UDP client is below:

```
    public class AsyncSendUdp extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    InetAddress inet_addr;
    DatagramSocket socket;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        byte[] ip_bytes = new byte[]{(byte) 192, (byte) 168, (byte) 0, (byte) 11};
        try {
            inet_addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip_bytes);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        char[] bufc = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (byte) bufc[i];
        }
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, inet_addr, 0xbac0);
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            socket.send(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I send as follows:

```
new AsyncSendUdp().execute("mmm");
```

I don't understand where is the problem.
Any ideas please!

Answer (score 1):

You're never actually reading for incoming messages. You'll want something like:

```
byte[] inBuffer = new byte[N];
DatagramPacket inPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuffer, inBuffer.length);
while (!exitCondition) {
    socket.receive(inPacket);
    // do something with your received packet
}
```

Comment: The code I use to receive is in marked answer of above reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752205/simple-udp-server-for-android-and-get-multi-messages      It works. It permanenly ready to receive. My problem is that receive does not work after sending UDP. Maybe the answer from the test box comes too fast? And my UDP server code is not ready to receive after sending a packet?  I have no other ideas. But I can't insert delays. The app should process packets very fast. Very starange performance....

Comment: I can't insert delays to the box between it receive the packet from  my app and feedback. I can't change the box performance. Strange Wifi problems? But I see the same performance on the emulator. Computer is connected to my local network by wires.